# Подскажите, как открыть исходный код в Intellij Idea в новом проекте?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Создал, загрузил, открыл новый проект в **Intellij Idea** и вижу иерархию вместо исходного кода, надписи с командами. Пытался решить проблему сам, но не справился.

Comment: Возможно вам нужно выпадающее меню прямо над списком команд? И там выбрать project

Comment: покажите скриншот. Возможно это заставка, когда не открыто никакого файла. Попробуйте из иерархии открыть какой-нибудь файл

Answer (score 2):

Если это новоый проект, то скорее всего сначала необходимо создать файлы исходного кода. Для этого:

1. В иерархии проекта ПКМ по папке src
2. Выбрать New
3. Java Class
4. Создать класс с необходимым именем

Все, теперь вы можете писать код